# How to Program a Spring with Hibernate web app?

Tags: spring, hibernate

I am Working on web application where i have 90 fields for a Person class which are divided in to family details,education details, personal details etc....

I want separate form for each, like for family details has-father name, mother name siblings etc... fields and so on for  other

I want separate table for each detail with common reference id for all tables

My question is how many bean classes should i write? Is it with one bean class can i map from multiple forms to multiple tables?

```
class PersonRegister{
  private Long iD;
  private String emailID;
  private String password;
   .
    .

     }//for register.......
```

once logged in i need to maintain his/her details

Either

```
class person{
}
```

or

```
class PersonFamilyDetails{}
class PersonEducationDetails{} 
etc
```

which way software developing standards specify to create?

Answer (score 0):

Don't go overboard, I believe in your case single but very *wide* (i.e. with a lot of columns) table would be most efficient and simplest from maintenance perspective. Only thing to keep in mind is too query only for a necessary subset of columns/fields when loading lots of rows. Otherwise you'll be fetching kilobytes of unnecessary data, not needed for particular use case.

Unfortunately Hibernate doesn't have direct support for that, when designing a mapping for `Person`, you'll end up with huge class and even worse - Hibernate will always fetch all simple columns (and many-to-one relationships). You can however overcome this problem either by creating several views in the database containing only subset of columns or by having several Java classes mapping to the same table but only to subset of columns.

Splitting your database model into several tables is beneficial only if your schema is not normalized. E.g. when storing siblings first name and last name you may wish to have a separate `Sibling` table and next time some other family member is entered, you can *reuse* the same row. This makes database smaller and might be faster when searching by sibling.

Answer (score 0):

Your question comes down to database normalization, as described in-depth by Boyce and Codd, see
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization.

The main advantage of database normalization is avoiding modification anomalies. In your case, if you got one table with for each person e.g. **father-firstname** and **father-lastname**, and you have multiple people with the same father, this data will be duplicated, and when you discover a typo in the father-lastname, you could modify it for one sibling, and not for the next.

In this simplified case, database design best practices would call for a first normalization into a separate table with **father-id**, **father-firstname** and **father-lastname**, and your **person** table having a one-to-many relation to it.

For one-to-one relations, e.g. **person**->**personeducationdetails**, there's some debate. In the original definition of 1st Normal Form, every optional field would be normalized by putting it's own table. This was later weakened by introducing 'null' in relational databases, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form#cite_note-CoddRule-12. But still, if a whole set of columns could be null at the same time, you put them in a separate table with a one-to-one relation.

E.g. if you don't know a person's educationdetails, all of its related fields are null, so you better split them off in a separate table, and simply not have a **personeducationdetails** record for that **person**.